# How would one prove the existence of the following indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Find out whether or not the following integral exists

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+1)}dx$$

My idea was to split the integral into two

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+1)}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+1)}dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+1)}dx$$

I'm pretty sure both integrals exist but I can't seem to find a way to prove this. Can someone please explain how one would argue.

Comment: There is no problem at $0$ because $\sin(x)/x$ converges (to $1$) for $x\to 0$.

Comment: Fancy approach: the given integral equals $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s^2+1}\,ds$$ which is clearly convergent and simple to estimate through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It is $\approx \frac{\pi}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$.

Comment: why use "Indefinite integral" in title and tag?

Comment: Query: Since by partial fractions $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+1)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)}dx$ is it enough to prove that the Sine Integral exists over the interval used to also cover other cases where the denominator is always $>x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's much simpler to note that$$\bigl(\forall x\in[1,+\infty)\bigr):\left|\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}\right|\leqslant\frac1{x^2}.$$Note that there's no problem at $0$, since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}=1.$$

Comment: @nicomezi: there is no problem at zero: $\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}$, defined as $1$ at $x=0$, is continuous over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @nicomezi I've just added a sentence to explain why there's no problem at $0$.

Comment: I agree with you, but this seemed to be part of the question. Thanks for the edit. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Split in two

- near $0$: $\;\sin x\sim_0 x$, so
  $$\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}\sim_0 \frac 1{x+1},$$
  and as the latter is integrable on $[0,1]$ and they're positive functions, the former is too.
- near $\infty$
  : 
  $$\biggl|\frac{\sin x}{x(x+1)}\biggr|=O\biggl(\frac 1{x^2}\biggr),$$

which is integrable on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: What? Isn't $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x+1}=\left.\log\frac1{x+1}\right|_0^1=\log 2$?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I shouldn't have Fixed. Of course. Thanks for pointing it!